# Get data from other sheet cell if condition

Tags: google-sheets

I have two sheets. In the first one I have numeric data, and in second is a table to check.

If in my second table I have empty cell do nothing, but if it have a cross (X) I want to get data from other sheet cell.

I've tested this:

=IF(LEN(B3) ;="Sheet 1"!B14 ; 0)

I check if B3 is not empty, and the i want to get B14 value from Sheet 1.

But i'm getting a parse error.

Thanks

Comment: Please explain it a little bit better. Well I'll try to answer as best as I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I created two Sheets: Sheet1 & Sheet2. In the cell A8 in Sheet1 there as value, any, for example "X". In the cell B8 of the Sheet2 there's a text value, it can be any, for example "Hello!". It should be like this:

[image]

Then If I want to display The value in the cell B8 of Sheet2 in the cell B8 of Sheet1, you need to write this function in the cell B8 of Sheet1:

Write the value of B8(Sheet2) in case there's a something in A8 (Sheet1). Else, write a 0:

```
=IF (LEN(A8) > 0; Sheet2!B8; 0)
```

or in case there's no cross ('X') just write an empty string:

```
=IF (LEN(A8) > 0; Sheet2!B8; "")
```

So if there's a value A8 (Sheet1), a "Hello!" will be displayed in B8 (Sheet1) which is directly taken from B8 of Sheet2. If there's no value, a 0 is displayed (or en empty string, depending which solution you took).

[image]

Comment: Hi Eder,I have done what you wrote me:
=IF(LEN(B3)>0 ;"Tarifas cliente"!B14 ; 0)
The problem is the sheet name. I've written it between quotes and without them, and doesn't work. Don't know what happens.

Comment: try with single quotes:

Comment: =IF(LEN(B3)>0 ;'Tarifas cliente'!B14 ; 0)

Comment: If it's correct , please vote up and mark it as correct answer.

Comment: Perfect Eder... Was the quotes! Thanks!

Comment: Can't vote yet! Have a poor karma. So if you can vote me will be great.